# Insert an image into a word document in Java

Tags: java, ms-word

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to insert an image into a word document in Java?

Answer (score 2):

What format is the word file you want to modify ? (OLE2, WordML, docx ?)

Generally the most widely used library for MSOffice file modification is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Also [this tutorial](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images) will probably be helpful in your current case.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea:

At first you will need to download the WordAPI, which can be downloaded right [here](http://www.must.de/WordAPI.exe). To create word documents with JAVA, there's a class doing everything you need. The class is called [WordProcessing](http://www.must.de/WordProcessing.java).

Here's a short preview of the methods implemented in that class:

- createNewDocumentFromTemplate(String templateName)
- createNewDocumentFromTemplateToSelectByUser()
- setNoteNotMatchingBookmarks(boolean noteNotMatchingBookmarks)
- typeTextAtBookmark(String bookmark, String textToType)
- typeTextAtBookmark(String bookmark, String[] linesToType)
- changeDocumentDirectory(String documentDirectory)
- saveDocumentAs(String documentName)
- saveDocumentAsAndClose(String documentName)
- closeDocument()
- printAndForget()
- printToPrinterToSelectByUserAndForget()
- printAndForget(String printerName)
- executeMacro(String macroName)            <---- Interesting for you
- quitApplication()
- exec()

As you can see there are a lot of helpful functions to create your document.

Now you can insert an image by calling the executeMacro function.

The Macro could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertPicture()

   Dim sPath As String
   Dim sBildPfad As String
   Dim lRes As Long

   'The path of your picture
   sBildPfad = "C:\temp"

   'remember the current path of the picture
   sPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(Path:=wdPicturesPath)

   'changing the path
   Options.DefaultFilePath(Path:=wdPicturesPath) = sBildPfad

   'open dialog
   lRes = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture).Show

   'reset path
   Options.DefaultFilePath(Path:=wdPicturesPath) = sPath

   If lRes <> 0 And ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
      'if inserted, changing the size
      Call PicSize(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count))
   End If

End Sub

Sub PicSize(oPic As InlineShape)
   Dim iScale As Single
   Dim iWidth As Single

   iWidth = 200 ' (pixel)

   oPic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   ' scaling
   iScale = (iWidth / oPic.Width) * 100
   oPic.ScaleWidth = iScale
   oPic.ScaleHeight = iScale
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the argument macroname, should contain the code of macro, if not how can we pass it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming docx is OK, you could use docx4j.  The [AddImage](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/AddImage.java) sample includes:

```
org.docx4j.wml.P p = newImage( wordMLPackage, bytes, 
            filenameHint, altText, 
            id1, id2 );
// Now add our p to the document
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(p);
```

No need to be running Word for docx4j to work.

ps Since your question is tagged "swing", you may wish to Google "docx4all" for a docx word processor implemented using Swing, which displays images.

Comment: i tried this, but i have't succeed with this. what is the use of AddImage.java file. i gone through the code but i have't get clear idea.could u please explain me what is the use of this code.