# How can I add an Image to MSWord document using Java

Tags: java, image, ms-word

How can I add an Image stored in my local computer to a word file using Java code.
Please let me know any API's that I can use. Or any sample code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert an image into a word document in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941744/insert-an-image-into-a-word-document-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Consider Apache POI [ApachePOI](http://poi.apache.org/)

POI is an API for manipulating MS office documents.
Know more here:[Duplicate ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674115/how-to-add-a-picture-to-a-docx-document-with-apache-poi-xwpf-in-java)

and one more [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745466/insert-picture-in-word-document)

Comment: thanks..let me go through them

Comment: HI ..I used the code as mentioned in these links but i get the following error- Exception occurred during playback of script [ImagetoWord] [CRFCN0019E: RationalTestScriptException on line 53 of script ImagetoWord - org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13].].

Comment: @ Sachin Verma i used this code         CustomXWPFDocument document = new CustomXWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\doc1.docx")));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\doc3.docx"));
        String id = document.addPictureData(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\a.jpg")), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        document.createPicture(id,document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG), 64, 64);
        document.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();